# get some sort of static reference in windows window callback

Tags: winapi, rust

I am kind of new to rust programming. I learned a lot over the last 2 months, but at the moment I'm at a point where I could use some educated advice.

In the past I was following along a C++ tutorial series to build an Engine with DirectX11 ([see this](https://wiki.planetchili.net/index.php/Hardware_3D_Series_(C%2B%2B_DirectX_Graphics))) to a certain point. After learning about Rust I decided to move the project to Rust and learn more about it along the way.

So what I want to reproduce is, the way the tutorial inserted a pointer to the window class into the window callback. I managed to acchieve it by implementing

```
// inside 'impl BEWindow'
extern "system" fn initialize_proc(window:HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
        unsafe {
            if message == WM_CREATE {
                let pCreate = *(lparam.0 as *const c_void as *const CREATESTRUCTA);
                let wnd = pCreate.lpCreateParams as *mut BEWindow;
                SetWindowLongPtrW(window, GWLP_USERDATA, *(wnd as *mut isize));
                SetWindowLongPtrW(window, GWLP_WNDPROC, BEWindow::run_proc as *const c_void as isize);
                let ret =wnd.as_ref().unwrap().handle_message(window, message, wparam, lparam);
                return ret
   }
}

extern "system" fn run_proc(window:HWND, message:u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) ->LRESULT {
        unsafe {
            if let Some(optional_wnd) = &GLOBAL_WND {
                let mut wnd = optional_wnd.lock().unwrap();
                return wnd.handle_message(window, message, wparam, lparam)
            }
            else {
                LRESULT(0)
            }
        }
    }
```

this kind of worked short term. After the first few iterations of the callback the referenced struct moved and I got a Segmentation fault because the pointer in the user data was not updated.

After some research I found Arc and Mutex to look kinda suitable for my problem. As far as I understood the tutorial the 'extern "system" callback' should be executed by a window thread.

I was wondering if I even need the initialize_proc to put the pointer into the UserData, when I could also use a static.

```
static mut GLOBAL_WND: Option<Arc<Mutex<BEWindow>>> = None;

//struct BEWindow
impl BEWindow{
   //other functions
   // new function sets the value of GLOBAL_WND to Some( ... arc ...) and returns a cloned 
   // version of the arc, it also creates the window with the winapi 
   extern "system" fn run_proc(window:HWND, message:u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) ->LRESULT {
        unsafe {
            if let Some(optional_wnd) = &GLOBAL_WND {
                let mut wnd = optional_wnd.lock().unwrap();
                return wnd.handle_message(window, message, wparam, lparam)
            }
            else {
                LRESULT(0)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this does not seem to work. The static never really gets updated. When debugging: In the Callback the static seems to always None.

So I think I lack some understanding of statics in rust and how they behave with multi-threading.
It could also be something with the order of actions in my new function. ( I dont have a minimal example of it by now)

I would be open to some alternative structure of the code. What I really want to acchieve by getting the pointer is to filter the messages I got from windows put them into some queues and access them from a game loop in the main thread.
I think this could be acchieved by some less complex code.

Comment: `static mut X: Option<Arc<…>>` is wrong on many levels, for one I'd almost consider `static mut` a mistake in Rust as it's never needed and ***very*** hard to get right. Secondly `static`s are already shared, so there is no need for `Arc` wich just helps you share ownership. For your case I'd not use a `static` at all, that just get's messy down the line.

Comment: @cafce25 Hm so maybe I should try to move the arc via the createstruct to the windows callback. That way I could get around the static. But I cant think of any other solution

Comment: I'd make the implicit global a proper parameter.

Comment: @cafce25 Make it a parameter of the run_proc? As far as I know I can not change the signature of the callback. It is expected by the winapi this way

Comment: Ah yea if you can't change the signature, then that's not possible, in that case your original attempt using the userdata should be used to pass the pointer around, just make sure you for example `Box::pin` but more importantly never move the data, that way the pointer remains valid. A global variable is a very poor solution to simply not move the data.

Comment: Have a look into the [`win-win`](https://crates.io/crates/win-win) crate. [This](https://github.com/raphlinus/win-win/blob/b3c21b70456fd2c002ddc6f7937925997fd15874/src/window.rs#L271C1-L301C2) is the important part of its implementation. That data itself is stored behind an `Rc<Box<_>>`.

Answer (score 0):

the comment of @IInspectable got me to the right path.

The [win-win](https://github.com/raphlinus/win-win/blob/b3c21b70456fd2c002ddc6f7937925997fd15874/src/window.rs#L271C1-L301C2) crate is a good example of how to inject a struct into the window procedure using an Rc.

Great find!